# Modulus of rigidity inside the water

Tags: waves, elasticity, stress-strain

Transverse wave can't travel inside the water. It travels in solid and on the surface of water because they have modulus of rigidity.
What is [modulus of rigidity](http://www.google.com/search?as_epq=modulus+of+rigidity)? and why there is no modulus of rigidity inside the water but on the surface?

Answer (score 3):

I think you're talking about the [shear modulus](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shear_modulus).

[image: Shear modulus]

(picture from the Wikipedia link above)

If you take a block of some material and apply a sideways force $F$ the shear strain is defined as:

$$ \gamma = \frac{x}{l} $$

The shear stress is the applied force divided by the area over which it's applied:

$$ \sigma = \frac{F}{A} $$

And the shear modulus is the stress divided by the strain:

$$ G = \frac{\sigma}{\gamma} = \frac{Fl}{Ax} $$

So a high shear modulus means the material is very hard to deform sideways and conversely a low shear stress means the material is very easy to deform sideways.

In water, and indeed all (Newtonian) fluids, the shear modulus is zero because if you apply a force $F$ the liquid simply flows and the strain becomes arbitrarily large. This is why transverse waves won't propagate in fluids, because a transverse wave is a shear wave.

Comment: It says here - https://www.saylor.org/site/wp-content/uploads/2011/04/Viscosity.pdf - that all fluids have resistance to shear stress and are therefore viscous. So it seems water does have a non-zero shear modulus, unless the author of that text is incorrect?

Comment: @csss: In viscous flow the stress $\sigma$ is given by $\sigma = \eta\dot\gamma$, where $\eta$ is the viscosity and $\dot\gamma$ is the strain rate. So when the fluid isn't flowing, i.e. when $\dot\gamma=0$ the stress is also zero. A material with a non-zero shear modulus can have a non-zero stress even when $\dot\gamma=0$. That is why the shear modulus is different from the viscosity.